# WF 4.0: how to get ActivityDesigner from an activity

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, wpf-4.0

I use this code to bind a `CustomDesigner` to a `CustomActivity`

```
AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomActivity), new DesignerAttribute(typeof(CustomDesigner)));
MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
```

How can I get an instance of `CustomDesigner` from an instance of `CustomActivity`.

See this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: My purpose of getting the designer is to set the the activity's location in the workflow designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view service to achiveve this.

```
designer.Context.Services.GetService<ViewService>().GetView(temp)
```

temp is the modelitem of flow activity
designer is the WorkflowDesigner